# Empty kubernetes VPA recommendations

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, resources, monitoring

I have the following manifest:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-rec-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-rec-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-rec-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-rec-container
          image: nginx
```

---

```
apiVersion: autoscaling.k8s.io/v1
kind: VerticalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: my-rec-vpa
spec:
  targetRef:
    apiVersion: "apps/v1"
    kind:       Deployment
    name:       my-rec-deployment
  updatePolicy:
    updateMode: "Off"
```

When I run it with (kubectl get vpa my-rec-vpa --output yaml), I have the following output for recco:

```
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-05-17T11:10:32Z"
    status: "False"
    type: RecommendationProvided
  recommendation: {}
```

What is the problem with recommendations?

Comment: Please refer to this [document](https://medium.com/infrastructure-adventures/vertical-pod-autoscaler-deep-dive-limitations-and-real-world-examples-9195f8422724).